# Deploying ServiceStack App to IIS Subfolder under Root

Tags: iis, servicestack

I have a simple ServiceStack application that I was able to host as a console app and I'm now wanting to package/deploy it for IIS.

I've created an ASP.Net application project and can successfully run the service on my local machine. When I tried to deploy it to an IIS server (v7.5) in a subfolder under root, I get a 404.

Per the examples and documentation on the ServiceStack site, I set location path web.config setting like this

```
<location path="api">
    ...
</location>
```

I tried these paths

```
/api
/subfolder_name/api
```

but none work.

Is it not possible to have it in a subfolder and have it the path of api?

I have it in a subfolder under the root and have the path config'd like this: . Yet it doesn't work. So does that mean that all of my files have to be under the root and then I have to alter the global.asax to include my apphost init code? Seems a little messy to me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of your exact setup but specifying the path in AppHost.Configure() may also help:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
});
```